# PHPMailer clearAllRecipients() not working in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, phpmailer

I am creating a plugin for WordPress that sends out a periodic newsletter using WordPress's built-in PHPMailer class. I have everything working correctly, but I want to send individual emails out to a specified number of recipients per hour.

I am pulling a number of email addresses from my database and running them through a `foreach` loop to send out individual emails and I am attaching each one through the addAddress() function.

To ensure I only send one email per address, I am trying to use `clearAllRecipients()` at the beginning of the loop, but this is not working. If I have my "email addresses per hour" set at 3, all 3 each email addresses is receiving 3 separate emails.

I also tried to run the list through the `foreach` loop and just run `addAddress` for each and use one `send` statement, but I still get 3 separate emails for each of the three addresses.

Below is my `foreach` loop. I can't figure out how am doing it wrong. Please help.

```
foreach ( $list as $e ) {
    $phpmailer->clearAllRecipients();
    $phpmailer->addAddress($e['email']);
    if ( $phpmailer->Send() ) {
        // Update the member row in the db. update the "checked" column to 1 so it will be skipped next pass through
        $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "UPDATE {$q_vars['members']} SET checked = %d WHERE id = %d", 1, $e['id']  ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you’re getting multiple emails with that code, it means your script as a whole is being run multiple times, not that a single run of the script is sending duplicates. You can verify this by appending a random number to your subject line. This is commonly caused by browser plugins that resubmit requests unnecessarily, but it may be because your code is being called by Wordpress for other reasons - adding some logging would reveal that.

Comment: Thanks, Synchro. I did just that to test it before I posted. I appended a random number to the subject line and it is running through the `foreach` multiple times. The thing is, when I run my `foreach` loop with just the standard `mail()` function, it doesn't happen. There is nothing different with each `foreach` loop, so I am confused.

Comment: Sounds like you need to run it in a debugger so you can watch what it's doing, but still, if the foreach loop is running more times than you expect, it's not the fault of the contents of the loop. I would be suspicious of the contents of `$list`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, typical PEBCAK error. Sorry! I had inadvertently wrapped my if/else statement to see which mail method to use in an identical `foreach` loop. So, I was running a `foreach` from my list, then checking which mail method to use, THEN running an identical `foreach` within that. I am stupid. Problem solved.